# Regex boundary words with special characters within

Tags: php, regex

So

I have an array with some bad words

```
$badsWords = ['stackoverflow', 'php', 'coding', 'life'];
```

These can then be used as:

```
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
                "/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")(en|ar)?\b/i",
                $string,
                $matches
              );
```

So if my test input is: `stackoverflow` it would match.

Is it possible to find a match in a test input like: `s.t.a.ckoverflow`?

One way is to split the string, word by word and then check against each item in the array if any of the word in the string can be matched. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd consider preg_replace()'ing special chars away and matching then

Comment: Wow @bwoebi I didn't even think about being able to do that :p That's smart, thanks you.

Comment: If you're looking at making a profanity filter, read up on the [Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) and its inverse. What'll happen when you encounter the string "gra**php**lotter"?